# Pass an implementation of an object without casting

Tags: java, interface, downcast

I apologize ahead of time for the title.

I am trying to pass an object `Cat` that implements `Animal` to an interface called `Groom`. In my `Groom` that handles grooming of `Cat` implementation, I have to downcast my object to understand what I am grooming, because the `Groom` interface accepts `Animal` as the parameter.

```
public interface Groom {
    void groom(Animal animal);
}

public class CatGroomer implements Groom {
    void groom(Animal animal) {
        Cat cat = (Cat) animal; // <---- how can i avoid this downcast
    }
}

public interface Animal {
    void do();
    void animal();
    void things();
}

public class Cat implements Animal {
    ...
}
```

Comment: But isn't the point of CatGroomer to only handle Cat objects and use Cat specific methods?

Comment: Groom should be generic: Grrom<T extends Animal>. CatGroomer should implement Groom<Cat>.

Comment: Using downcast in most cases says that tou are using inheritance wrongly. By saying that `CatGroomer implements Groom` you are stating that `CatGroomer` should be able to groom any animal. Better if you describe a task you are trying to solve, so we could advice you with better design.

Comment: I apologize for the very rudimentary example. Unfortunately I cannot rearrange the underlying implementations and have a very limited scope in what I am able to actually work with. The scenario I am dealing with makes a little more sense, not so much the example I provided.

Comment: A good solution mostly depends on scenarios how `Groom` is used and how its `animal` argument is passed. The solution with generic is just moving the type problem away from this piece of code, but it will appear in other place.

Comment: @kan This is what I am mostly concerned about. Unless there is a way to define in `CatGroomer`'s implementation of `groom()` that the parameter is of type `Animal` but only accepts implementations that use `Cat` (without generics).

Comment: What's the reason that CatGroomer should implement the interface? Why not just `public class CatGroomer {  void groom(Cat cat){...} }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Groom` could be made generic like this:

```
interface Groom<T extends Animal> {
  void groom(T t);
}

public class CatGroomer implements Groom<Cat> {
  void groom(Cat animal) {

  }
}
```

Comment: I was going to try without using generics but I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: Generics are meant to be used in those cases that you are facing currently.